# Why is SQL Alchemy database engine still None?

Tags: api, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am following the factory design pattern. In the WSGI.py file, why does print(db) prints

```
<SQLAlchemy engine=None>
```

I have attached the app to db with db.init_app(app) command in MAIN.py file. Shouldn't the output be

```
<SQLAlchemy engine= "sqlite:///site.db">
```

My WSGI.py file

```
from main import create_app, db

app = create_app("sqlite:///site.db")
print(db)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My MAIN.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app(URI) :
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = URI
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```